# .htaccess redirect subdomain to custom URL

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I actually want to redirect **name.domain.com** to **domain.com/user/name**. So coded .htaccess as follow

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)% http://domain.com/user/%1 [R,L]
```

However, I'm getting 404 error. Can you please advice me to code the .htaccess correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/user%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]
```